# Returning a Value to BackBone.js while saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So I am using backbone.js, and I am trying to save a Model.  On the server side I am generating a GUID for the Model that gets received and I am returning that GUID so that way the Model has it on the client side.

My function is as such

```
    this.save({},
        {
            success: function (model, response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (model, response) {
                alert(response)
            }
        });
```

It sends the object to the server, it returns the value I want from the post.  It returns a (`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) and yet it calls the error function (which has my proper return value in it)
Any ideas why?

I did the following in the console

```
JSON.stringify(response)
"{"readyState":4,"responseText":"5dad212e-73bf-4e01-911a-397b81f77022","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}"
```

So it is getting back the 200 and the guid but not firing success.... I really don't want to just use the error function as that's not what should be firing :p

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try explicitly putting one model value in the first parameter of your save call.  The docs mention that only the specified attributes of that hash are saved.  Also, what are the contents of the model argument in the error function?

Comment: Adding a param didn't help.  However your question about what is in the model is interesting.  
The model appeared fine at first glance.  However when I tried `JSON.stringfy(model)` I got `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`
I noticed there was an attribute that had a circular reference and set it to null and I was able to stringify it.

Thing is I can stringify the model BEFORE it is saved but not the model in the callback....

Comment: I fixed the circular reference.  Another callback was firing before that callback finished.  I moved the function that calls the other call back into the callback we are looking at (yes confusing... there is a lot going on)
I can now JSON.stringify the model that comes back in the error but it still doesn't work so I don't think that was the problem (but it would have been another one later, thank you!)

Comment: How do you return `json` from server side ? Can you give this a try, like return json `{ "guid" : "id_to_be_returned" //, other fields to be added }` and make the response type `json`. Coz it seems there's something wrong with the response returned.

Comment: Ah you're 100% correct!  I was returning a straight up GUID from .net. I wrapped that into Json() and it worked perfectly.  Please specify an answer that I am not returning the data back in json format and I will mark it as correct

Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped !! Just posted answer :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your `resposneText`, it seems server is not returning acceptable response - not a proper `json` object. Make the server return response like,

```
{ 
  "guid" : "id_to_be_returned" //, 
  // and other attributes to be added in the model 
}
```

And make the response type as `json`. It should work.